# Passing Nullable Columns to a Function Causes Warning SR0007 - Even Though the Function uses COALESCE and ISNULL Inside

Tags: sql, sql-server, code-analysis, sql-server-data-tools

I had a predicate which was repeated in many different WHERE clauses, so I "cleverly" refactored it out into a scalar-valued function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsCurrent
(
    @FromDate DATE,
    @ToDate DATE,
    @AsOfDate DATE
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Today DATE;
    SET @Today = COALESCE(@AsOfDate, GETDATE());

    RETURN
         CASE
             WHEN @Today BETWEEN ISNULL(@FromDate,'1900-01-01') AND ISNULL(@ToDate, DATEADD(dd, 1, @Today))
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0
         END;
END
```

As you can see, the function *expects* to be passed NULL values for any of the parameters, and handles them correctly. It will always produce either a 1 or a 0.

But when I call that function, passing a nullable column as one of the parameters, I get warning SR0007 from code analysis:

> SR0007 : Microsoft.Rules.Data : Nullable columns can cause final results to be evaluated as NULL for the predicate.

Is there anything I can do to keep these warnings from appearing for calls to this particular function? I've adopted a rule of having no code analysis warnings on any code I change. I hope I don't have to use `ISNULL` on the parameters just to get SSDT code analysis to shut up. Is there a way I can "give it a hint"?

---

When I said "give it a hint", I was thinking about how ReSharper does things. Not only can you control which warnings come up with which severity, you can also disable a particular instance of a warning, through a pragma or comment in the code, or you can use annotations. For instance, I could put a `[NotNull]` annotation on a parameter to indicate that it will never be null. I was hoping there would be something similar, or something with the same effect.

Comment: Just a guess -- does it help if you add default values to the parameters? `@FromDate DATE = NULL, ...`

Comment: @Keith: on first attempt, I couldn't get default values to work in the function. I was still required to pass all the parameters.

Comment: Default parameters in SQL functions are counter-intuitive IMHO. You still need to specify each parameter when calling the function. But I was hoping this approach would give code analysis the hint you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can right-click on the warning in the Error List and choose "Suppress Static Code Analysis Message(s)". This will suppress all cases of the SR0007 error in that particular file. It will still be raised in other files (which it sounds like is what you want). Alternatively if you don't ever want to see these warnings, disable the rule in your project properties.

Edit: What happens is a file called StaticCodeAnalysis.SuppressMessages.xml is created with the following entry:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StaticCodeAnalysis version="2" xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.StaticCodeAnalysis">
  <SuppressedFile FilePath="DatabaseScalarFunction1.sql">
    <SuppressedRule Category="Microsoft.Rules.Data" RuleId="SR0007" />
  </SuppressedFile>
</StaticCodeAnalysis>
```

As you can see this filters the displayed errors/warnings first by file name, then by rule ID. So any warnings with ID "SR0007" in the file "DatabaseScalarFunction1.sql" will be ignored. If you had multiple procedures in this one file, it would ignore the warning for all of them.

Comment: What do you mean "in that particular file"? You mean in the entire stored procedure? That would work well enough, though I would still miss any legitimate cases of SR0007 in that stored procedure.

Comment: I've added an explanation of what happens - it does mean that legitimate cases are filtered out too. If you want to request a fix for the underlying behavior I'd suggest opening a Connect bug to improve the rule's behavior - go to  https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx and use the category "Developer Tools(SSDT, BIDS, etc.)".

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. BTW if you're working at Microsoft, you might want to say so in your profile, as a matter of disclosure.

Comment: Thanks John, I didn't realize I was missing that info - fixed now.